# export table from PostgreSQL with ogr2ogr

Tags: sql, postgis, ogr2ogr

I want to export a table inside my database as an MapInfo File. I will use the tool ogr2ogr.
this is the commend I found in the docu:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" test.mid PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=Ocean_Extraction password=admin" "tablec"
```

after this I get an error message:

**ERROR 6: Unable to open test.mif.
ERROR 1: MapInfo File driver failed to create test.mif**

How can I avoid this? I do not want to open this file. I will create a new one base on the database table...

Comment: Your code is ok and should work. Probably you cannot create files in the current directory because of missing permissions. Try executing the command in your home directory. Are you working on linux, windows or mac?

Comment: I am working on windows 10...it is still not working ERROR 6: Unable to open test.mid

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your ogr2ogr is not configured with the mapinfo driver.

You can check the supported formats with
ogr2ogr --formats

If you can't find mapinfo in that list, you need an ogr2ogr configured with mapinfo support, or you need to build it from source.

Comment: No MapInfo File is in the supported list.